# Height of the LoTR Races

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, elves, hobbits, races, orcs

Is the height of races (men, elves, orcs, goblins, etc.) ever mentioned by Tolkien? If not, did the movies just make up the various heights?

Comment: Are you joking? You'd be surprised how incredible is amount of details about Middle-Earth. :)

Comment: Elves and human height: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10804/are-tolkien-elves-taller-or-shorter-than-men

Comment: about dwarves http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53848/how-much-does-the-average-adult-male-dwarf-weigh

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Men

**Númenóreans (2nd age) - 7'**

> Halflings was derived from the Numenorean name for them (in Sindarin Periannath). ... The name thus evidently referred to their height as compared with Numenorean men, and was approximately accurate when first given. The Numenoreans were a people of great stature.... **Their full-grown men were often seven feet tall.**
> <sub>Private memorandum critiquing Pauline Baynes’ poster-map, quoted in *The Lord of the Rings A Reader's Companion*</sub>

> **the Numenoreans before the Downfall were a people of great stature and strength, the Kings of Men; their full grown men were commonly seven feet tall, especially in the royal and noble houses.** In the North where men of other kinds were fewer and their race remained purer this stature remained more frequent, though in both Arnor and Gondor apart from mixture of race the Numenoreans showed a dwindling of height and of longevity in Middle-earth that became more marked as the Third Age passed.
> <sub>A "late, unpublished note" quoted in *The Lord of the Rings A Reader's Companion*</sub>

**Dúnedain (3rd age) - 6'4"**

> The Númenórean ranga was slightly longer than our yard, approximately thirty-eight inches, owing to their great stature. ... Account has to be taken both of the great stature of the Númenóreans (since hands, feet, fingers and paces are likely to be the origin of names of units of length), and also of the variations from these averages or norms in the process of fixing and organising a measurement system both for daily use and for exact calculations. Thus two rangar was often called "man-high," which at thirty-eight inches gives **an average height of six feet four inches; but this was at a later date, when the stature of the Dúnedain appears to have decreased**, and also was not intended to be an accurate statement of the observed average of male stature among them, but was an approximate length expressed in the well-known unit ranga.
> <sub>*Unfinished Tales* - "Númenórean Linear Measures"</sub>

**Elendil the Tall - nearly 2.5 ranga (=7'11") or 7'**

**Isildur - 7'**

> It is however said of the great people of the past that they were more than a man-high. **Elendil was said to be "more than man-high by nearly half a ranga;"** but he was accounted the tallest of all the Númenóreans who escape the Downfall.
> <sub>*Unfinished Tales* - "Númenórean Linear Measures"</sub>

> Aragorn, direct descendant of **Elendil and his son Isildur, both of whom had been seven feet tall**, must nonetheless have been a very tall man
> <sub>A "late, unpublished note" quoted in *The Lord of the Rings A Reader's Companion*</sub>

**Aragorn - 6'6"**

**Boromir - 6'4"**

> **Aragorn,** direct descendant of Elendil and his son Isildur, both of whom had been seven feet tall, **must nonetheless have been a very tall man ..., probably at least 6 ft. 6; and Boromir, of high Numenorean lineage, not much shorter (say 6 ft. 4).**
> <sub>A "late, unpublished note" quoted in *The Lord of the Rings A Reader's Companion*</sub>

**Rohirim - shorter than 6'4"**

**Éomer - 6'6"**

> **The Rohirrim were generally shorter,** for in their far-off ancestry they had been mingled with men of broader and heavier build. **Éomer was said to have been tall, of like height with Aragorn;** but he with other descendants of King Thengel were taller than the norm of Rohan, deriving this characteristic (together in some cases with darker hair) from Morwen, Thengel's wife, a lady of Gondor of high Númenórean descent.
> <sub>*Unfinished Tales* - "Númenórean Linear Measures"</sub>

## Dwarves

**Dwarves - about 4'**

> The description of the height of hobbits is perhaps unnecessarily vague and complicated in the Prologue.... But it boils down to this: **Dwarves were about 4 ft. high at least.** Hobbits were lighter in build, but not much shorter;...
> <sub>Private memorandum critiquing Pauline Baynes’ poster-map, quoted in *The Lord of the Rings A Reader's Companion*</sub>

## Hobbits

**Fallohides - taller than 3'6"**

**Harfoots - 3'6"**

**Stoors - shorter than 3'6"**

**Shire Hobbits - 3'-4', average of 3'5"**

**Hobbits today - less than 3'**

> Halflings was derived from the Númenórean name for them (in Sindarin Periannath). It was given first to the Harfoots, who became known to the rulers of Arnor in the eleventh century of the Third Age; later it was also applied to the Fallohides and Stoors. The name thus evidently referred to their height as compared with Númenórean men, and was approximately accurate when first given. The Númenóreans were a people of great stature. Their full-grown men were often seven feet tall.
> The descriptions and assumptions of the text are not in fact haphazard, and are based on a standard: the average height of a male adult hobbit at the time of the story. **For Harfoots this was taken as 3 ft. 6; Fallohides were slimmer and a little taller; and Stoors broader, stouter, and somewhat shorter.** The remarks in the Prologue [concerning the height of Hobbits] . .. are unnecessarily vague and complicated, owing to the inclusion of references to supposed modern survivals of the race in later times; but as far as the LR [Lord of the Rings] is concerned they boil down to this: **the hobbits of the Shire were in height between 3 and 4 feet in height, never less and seldom more.** They did not of course call themselves Halflings....
> Dwarves were about 4 ft. high at least. **Hobbits were lighter in build, but not much shorter; their tallest men were 4 ft.,** but seldom taller. **Though nowadays their survivors are seldom 3 ft. high,** in the days of the story they were taller which means that they usually exceeded 3 ft. and qualified for the name of halfling. But the name 'halfling' must have originated circa T[hird] A[ge] 1150, getting on for 2,000 years (1868) before the War of the Ring, during which the dwindling of the Numenoreans had shown itself in stature as well as in life-span. So that it referred to **a height of full-grown males of an average of, say, 3 ft. 5.**
> The dwindling of the Dunedain was not a normal tendency, shared by peoples whose proper home was Middle-earth; but due to the loss of their ancient land far in the West, nearest of all mortal lands to 'The Undying Realm'. The much later dwindling of hobbits must be due to a change in their state and way of life; they became a fugitive and secret people, driven as Men, the Big Folk, became more and more numerous, usurping the more fertile and habitable lands, to refuge in forest or wilderness: a wandering and poor folk, forgetful of their arts and living a precarious life absorbed in the search for food and fearful of being seen; for cruel men would shoot them for sport as if they were animals. In fact they relapsed into the state of 'pygmies'. The other stunted race, the Druedain, never rose much above that state.
> <sub>Private memorandum critiquing Pauline Baynes’ poster-map, quoted in *Unfinished Tales*, *The Lord of the Rings A Reader's Companion*, and *The Nature of Middle-earth*</sub>

**Bandobras Took - 4'5"**

> For they are a little people, smaller than Dwarves: less stout and stocky, that is, even when they are not actually much shorter. Their height is variable, ranging between two and four feet of our measure. They seldom now reach three feet; but they have dwindled, they say, and in ancient days they were taller. **According to the Red Book, Bandobras Took (Bullroarer), son of Isumbras the Third, was four foot five and able to ride a horse.** He was surpassed in all Hobbit records only by two famous characters of old; but that curious matter is dealt with in this book.
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* - Prologue 1 - "Concerning Hobbits"</sub>

**Bilbo - 3' or 3'6"**

> Actual size – only important if other objects are in picture – say **about three feet or three feet six inches.** The hobbit in the picture of the gold-hoard, Chapter XII, is of course (apart from being fat in the wrong places) enormously too large. But (as my children, at any rate, understand) he is really in a separate picture or 'plane' – being invisible to the dragon.
> <sub>1938 Letter to the Houghton Mifflin Company, published in *Letters of J.R.R Tolkien*</sub>

**Sam - 3'4"**

**Pippin - 3'4"**

**Frodo and Sam - between 3'4" and 3'6"**

> These figures [of the Fellowship] are thus all too short. Gandalf even bent must have been at least 5 ft. 6; Legolas at least 6 foot, (probably more); Gimli is about the height that the Hobbits should have been, but was probably somewhat taller; **the Hobbits should have been between 3 ft. 4 and 3 ft. 6. (I personally have always thought of Sam as the shortest, but the sturdiest in build, out of the four.)**
> <sub>Private memorandum critiquing Pauline Baynes’ poster-map, quoted in *The Nature of Middle-earth*</sub>

> 'Yes,' he said, 'they are quite plain: a hobbit's footprints. Pippin's I think. **He is smaller than the others.**
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* - Book III Chapter 2 - "The Riders of Rohan"</sub>

**Merry and Pippin after drinking ent-draughts - 4' or 4'6"**

> I am nearly twenty-nine, so I pass you there; though I am but **four feet**, and not likely to grow any more, save sideways.’
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* - Book V Chapter 1 - "Minas Tirith"</sub>

> Orcs, and talking trees, and leagues of grass, and galloping riders. and glittering caves, and white towers and golden halls, and battles, and tall ships sailing, all these passed before Sam’s mind until he felt bewildered. But amidst all these wonders he returned always to his astonishment at the size of Merry and Pippin; and he made them stand back to back with Frodo and himself. He scratched his head. ‘Can’t understand it at your age!’ he said. ‘But there it is: **you’re three inches taller than you ought to be,** or I’m a dwarf.’
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* - Book VI Chapter 4 - "The Field of Cormallen"</sub>

> According to the Red Book, Bandobras Took (Bullroarer), son of Isumbras the Third, was four foot five and able to ride a horse. **He was surpassed in all Hobbit records only by two famous characters of old; but that curious matter is dealt with in this book.**
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* - Prologue 1 - "Concerning Hobbits"</sub>

## Elves

**Male elves - at least 6'6"**

**Female elves - at least 6'**

> The *Quendi* [Elves] were in origin a tall people. The *Eldar* ... were those ... who accepted the invitation of the Valar to remove from Middle-earth and set forth on the Great March to the Western Shores of Middle-earth. They were in general the stronger and taller members of the Elvish folk at that time. **In Eldarin tradition it was said that even their women were seldom less than six feet in height; their full-grown elfmen no less than six and a half feet, while some of the great kings and leaders were taller.**
> <sub>A "late manuscript" quoted in *The Lord of the Rings A Reader's Companion*</sub>

**Galadriel - 6'4"**

> The Eldar of the Elder Days were also very tall. Galadriel, "the tallest of all the women of the Eldar of whom tales tell," was said to be man-high, but it is noted "according to the measure of the Dúnedain and the men of old," **indicating a height of about six feet four inches.**
> <sub>*Unfinished Tales* - "Númenórean Linear Measures"</sub>

**Celeborn**

> [Celeborn] was held by them to be tall, as his name indicated ("silver-tall"); but the Teleri were in general somewhat less in build and stature than the Noldor.
> <sub>*Unfinished Tales* - "Númenórean Linear Measures"</sub>

**Legolas - Between 6' and 6'6"**

> **Aragorn was the tallest of the Company**, but Boromir, little less in height, was broader and heavier in build.
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* - Book II Chapter 3 - "The Ring Goes South"</sub>

> These figures [of the Fellowship] are thus all too short. Gandalf even bent must have been at least 5 ft. 6; **Legolas at least 6 foot, (probably more);** Gimli is about the height that the Hobbits should have been, but was probably somewhat taller; the Hobbits should have been between 3 ft. 4 and 3 ft. 6. (I personally have always thought of Sam as the shortest, but the sturdiest in build, out of the four.)
> <sub>Private memorandum critiquing Pauline Baynes’ poster-map, quoted in *The Nature of Middle-earth*</sub>

## Istari

**Gandalf - between 5'6" and 6'6"**

> **Aragorn was the tallest of the Company**, but Boromir, little less in height, was broader and heavier in build.
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* - Book II Chapter 3 - "The Ring Goes South"</sub>

> But his colours were always white, silver-grey, and blue – except for the boots he wore when walking in the wild . . . **Gandalf even bent must have been at least 5 ft. 6 . . . Which would make him a short man even in modern England, especially with the reduction of a bent back.**
> <sub>Private memorandum critiquing Pauline Baynes’ poster-map, quoted in *The History of the Hobbit*</sub>

## Ainur

**Valar (regularly) - "Far greater" than 6'6"**

**Valar (when doing important deeds) - "awe inspiring heights"**

> The *fanar*[= visible form] of the great Valar were said by the Eldar who had dwelt in Valinor usually to have had **a stature far greater than that of the tallest Elves**, and when performing some great deed or rite, or issuing commands, to have assumed **an awe-inspiring height**.
> <sub>*The Nature of Middle-earth* - "The Visible Forms of the Valar and Maiar"</sub>

Comment: Pippin was *slighter* than Merry but nonetheless taller.

Comment: @Buzz - I was following Hammond & Scull, who interpret Christopher Tolkien's commentary about that line as a reference to Pippin's height. (They index it in *The Reader's Companion* under `Took, Peregrin ‘Pippin’, height`.)

Comment: "Gandalf even bent must have been at least 5 ft. 6" - so non-bent he'd be taller, wouldn't he? Or is he usually "bent"?

Comment: I don't think adding centimeters improves this answer when all of Tolkien quotes are in inches and feet. And centimeters often present a sense of precision not present in the original quotes.

Comment: @fez - The purpose of this answer is to present what Tolkien said. I'd strongly prefer it be more accurate to being more accessible. And it's trivial to google a conversion to a different measurement system if you're unfamiliar with the one with Tolkien was using.

Comment: @ibid - yep, 100% with you now! Sorry! I totally get it :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, he has, but as far as I remember, not for all the races.

- **Hobbits** were 3 to 4 feet tall  -- average 3 feet, 6 inches ( [Letter #27](http://www.tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Letter_27))

  > Actual size – only important if other objects are in picture – say about three feet or three feet six inches.
  >
  > <sub>[Source](http://www.e-reading.club/bookreader.php/139008/The_Letters_of_J.R.R.Tolkien.pdf.pdf)</sub>
- **Orcs** were 3 & 1/2 to 4 feet tall ( The Fellowship of the Ring)

The size of the Elves and the men was similar. There was a mention I think that the dwarves had similar height to the Hobbits, if not slightly taller.

Comment: What's your specific reference for orc height? That doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: @MattGutting I don't know but I'd guess that height would be for regular orcs. Not Uruk Hai.

Comment: Elves and men are of similar height, but not all men and elves are... Numenoreans and high elves are often more than 6'6, like Aragorn and the Dunadan, Celeborn and Galadriel (which is reputed very high for a woman). Elrond and his sons are also said to be very tall. 

Other men are usually more like the modern standard in height, between 5 and 6 feet high.

Uruks are almost normal man height, so I put them in the low 5'. But they are said to be very broad in chest.

Comment: The Goblins of the Misty Mountains are probably small like that. The Gundabad (e.g. Bolg) and Mordor orcs (e.g. Gorbag) should be more man-sized, if they stood up straight.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer, containing only statements from *The Hobbit* and *The Lord of the Rings*.

What is said in those books is certainly canon in those books.  What Tolkien wrote in letters and essays is "Word of God",  as TV Tropes puts it, and if there is any contradiction, fans will have to decide for themselves which to accept.

Of course the sizes of newborn babies, and growing children, will be a lot smaller than the sizes of adults.

Tolkien described Hobbits in the beginning of *The Hobbit*:

> The mother of our particular hobbit—-what is a hobbit? I suppose hobbits need some description nowadays, since they have become rare and shy of the Big People, as they call us. They are (or were) a little people, about half our height, and smaller than the bearded Dwarves.

If adult humans are usually about five to six feet tall, adult hobbits should have been about two and a half to three feet tall.

I read the above quote on January 1, 2024 in my paperback copy of *The Hobbit*, a revised edition dated to 1966. And this is different from what I remember from first reading *The Hobbit* long ago in what might have been the original edition. What I remembered it saying was that Hobbits were smaller than dwarves but larger than Lilliputians.

The answer by Ibid to this question:

[https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/283213/did-tolkien-change-the-description-of-hobbits-in-the-hobbit][1]

says that the first and second editions of *The Hobbit* did compare Hobbits to Lilliputians but it was changed for the third edition.

> They are (or were) small people, smaller than dwarves (and they have no beards) but very much larger than lilliputians.

Lilluptians were supposed to be 1/12 the height of Gulliver, and so about 6 inches tall.  So Tolkien always said that Hobbits were a lot taller than 6 inches, even before he wrote other things about their height.

I also note that in *The Return of the King*, Book V, chapter I, “Minas Tirith”, Pippin meets a boy named Bergil.  Bergil says he is ten years old and almost five feet tall.  Pippin says:

> I am nearly twenty-nine, so I pass you there; though I am but four feet and not likely to grow any more, save sideways.

Though as it turns out Pippin did later grow several inches, maybe half a foot or more.  Pippin thought that he was (approximately) four feet tall then, on March 9, Third Age 3019, but he was probably already growing taller than he thought he was.  About 11 days earlier, on February 29, 3019 (the calendar was different from ours) Merry and Pippin were given an Ent drink, which apparently magically caused them to grow much taller.  On April 6, 3019, at the Field of Cormallen, Samwise was amazed at how much taller Merry and Pippin were.

*The Return of the KIng*, Book VI, Chapter 4, "The Field of Cormallen" Says:

> Why look Frodo!  I fit isn't Pippin, or Mr. Peregrim Took I should say, and Mr. Merry! How they have grown!
>
> Orcs, and talking trees, and leagues of grass, and galloping riders, and glittering caves, and white towers and golden halls, and battles, and tall ships sailing, all these passed before Sam's mind until he felt bewildered.  But amidst all those wonders he returned always to his astonishment at the size of Merry and PIppin;  and he made them stand back to back with Frodo and himself.  He scratched his head.  'Can't understand it at your age!'  He said 'But there it is you're three inches taller than you ought to be, or I'm a Dwarf.'
>
> 'That you are not'  Said Gimli.  'But what did I say?  Mortals can not go drinking ent-draughts and expect no more to come of them than of a pot of beer.'

So by March 9 Pippin might have already been half an inch or so taller than he thought he was.  And eventually Pippin and Merry grew to be at least a little bit, and maybe more, taller than Bandobras "Bullroarer" Took who was four feet five inches tall.

Another answer to this question says that Merry and Pippin Were 3 feet 4 inches tall, presumably meaning when they left the Shire with Frodo, and that they later grew to to 4 feet 6 inches.  But at the field of Cormallen Sam says they are only 3 inches taller than they should be, not 4 to 14 inches, and about a month before the Field of Cormallen Pippin said he was 4 feet tall, so he was already about 8 inches taller than the reputed 3 feet 4 inches.  If Pippin grew from 3 feet 4 inches to 4 feet before the Field of Cormallen Sam would say that Pippin grew 8 inches, not 3 inches.

Therefore I judge that Pippin, and maybe Merry, was about 4 feet tall, taller than the average Hobbit, and not 3 feet 4 inches when they left the Shire.

*The Fellowship of the Ring*, the Prolog, I *Concerning Hobbits* says:

> For they are a little people, smaller than Dwarves: less stout and stocky, that is, even when they are not actually much shorter. Their height is variable, ranging between two and four feet of our measure. They seldom now reach three feet; but they have dwindled, they say, and in ancient times they were taller. According to the Red Book Bandobras Took (Bullroarer), son of Isengrim the Second, was four feet five and able to ride a horse. He was surpassed in Hobbit records only by two famous characters of old; but that curious matter is dwelt with in this book

That indicates that adult Hobbits two feet tall would be much shorter than adult dwarves, while adult Hobbits four feet tall might be the same size as Dwarves or only a little bit shorter. Thus I guess that most Dwarves probably have heights somewhere in the range of four to five feet. But I have no way of knowing whether adult Dwarf heights range from three and a half to four and half feet, or from four and a half feet to five feet, or whatever.